# @testable import moduleName not importing everything

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, unit-testing

I have a project that is mixed Obj-C and Swift and I am having some issues getting my unit tests to work.

I'm using the `@testable import moduleName` directive to import my files, however it does not appear to be importing all the files. I have full access to pretty much all of my Obj-C models, manager classes etc. but none of the view controllers (95% of which are in Obj-C) are available from within the `XCTestCase`, along with all of my Swift files.

I have imported `@testable import ModuleName` at the top of the XCTestCase,
I have also edited the target to enable testability, but the only way I can access these files seems to be if I set the files target membership manually, which if I have understood everything correctly, I should not need to do.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What did you mean by but none of the view controllers are available?
did you mean that you can not access any of the variables inside your file view controllers classes?

Comment: Sorry, not so clear. What I mean is none of my view controllers (all Obj-C) are available to me inside my XCTestCase class along with all of my Swift files, but other classes are available to be used as expected. Edited question to clarify.

Answer (score 4):

Yeah I just also went from the same problem about the Unit testing with the project having both **Objective-C & Swift** languages.
So basically what i found was 
You have to add the respective file and all the required files to Test target. And also required to add them to the **Bridging_Header** to access those files
Moreover the reason behind using the 
`@testable` 
is to test methods internal .... methods.

```
@testable import moduleName
```

This is used for the purpose of visibility of methods, i.e like internal methods can now be visible in unitTest but atill private methods won’t.

Comment: Thanks for details. 
Can you please give some more information, 
1. Do we have to add each files like LoginVC,HelpVC and related model files to test target? `Compile sources` in `Build Phases` should same as main target? 
2. Need to add `Link Binary with Libraries`?
We have **custom frameworks** added in our app,facing issues in accessing main target files from test target.

Any idea/suggestions?